# How To Reference a Main View Controller TextField from Another View Controller IBAction?

Tags: objective-c

I have a Main View Controller and a 'Preferences' View Controller.
There is a 'Save' button on the Preferences View Controller.
That `IBAction` is located in the main ViewController.m file.

After saving the preferences to `NSUserDefaults`, the IBAction pops back to the Main View Controller.

The last action here is to 'clear' one of the `UITextField`s on that Main View Controller window.

The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to reference that Main View Controller simply.

In VisualBasic we would say:  Window1.finalTextField.text = "";

What is the obj-c equivalent of finding that 'Window1'?
I've tried sub-classes for the ViewController, but that seems to only work for *other* Windows, not the Main View Controller.

The last line of code is not working:    **self.finalTextField.text = @"";**

```
- (IBAction)savePrefButton:(id)sender
    {
    int yPref = prefYsegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:yPref forKey:@"yPref"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Data saved");

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    self.finalTextField.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `finalTextField` is defined as an IBOulet in your Main View Controller than you can access it from within that viewcontroller simply by it's name:

```
[finalTextField setText:@""];
```

Of course be sure to link up the variable to the text field in IB.

If you want to access `finalTextField` on your main view controller, from your preferences view controller then you need to 1) create a property on your main view controller to expose that variable, and 2) pass a reference to your preferences view controller for your main view controller.

For example in property view controller .h:

```
MainViewController *mainViewController;

@property (nonatomic, weak) MainViewController *mainViewController;
```

Then in property view controller .m:

```
[self.mainViewController.finalTextField setText:@""];
```

Then when you push your segue (in the main view controller) be sure to set the reference back:

In prepareForSegue:

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"XXXX"])
{    
    PropertyViewController *propertyViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    propertyViewController.mainViewController = self;
}
```

note: change PropertyViewController and MainViewController to whatever the class names are for your property view controller and main view controller.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that if the mainViewController holds a strong or retaining reference to propertyViewController, this approach could create a retain cycle. To avoid this you could use a delegation pattern.

Comment: finalTextField is an IBOutlet:  @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *finalTextField;
But accessing it in that way does not work.
I have one ViewController.h and one ViewController.m file.
I am following the 2nd part of your answer, but the very last entry does not make sense to me. Where does that go? "propertyViewController.mainViewController = self;"

Comment: That would go right after you create and initialize your property view controller in your main view controller. Presumably you have somewhere that you initialize it and push it onto the nav controller. Before you push it onto the nav controller, set the reference back to main so you can use the reference in the property view controller.

Comment: @isaac, agree that delegation or a number of other ways to do this (post a notification, etc) are probably better. But he's clearly a beginner and trying to keep it simple. I'm not even sure if he's using ARC, so he'll have to figure out how to release any property references he creates.

Comment: I am using ARC. I am opening the Preferences window by using a segue push. There is no reference to it in ViewController.m using that method. So there is no place to put the propertyViewController code.

Comment: When a control-drag from button to new window is used to create a segue in XCode 4.6, it does not create any code in ViewController.m -- so there is no place to put the code you've outlined. I think this will have to be created manually. I'm working on that. Thank you though.